# Debian unable to initialize GTK+, is display set properly?

Tags: erlang, gtk, debian

I have a Debian jessie distribution with KDE X-server.
I installed the Erlang R17.5 package with smp-support.
Other installed packages are libwxwidgets*, gtk* and libncurses*.

I start the Erlang shell with erl -smp, so I can use observer.
When I start observer I get the error "Unable to initiliaze GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

I got this even when I try as root. I didn't ssh to my distribution and I want that this works even without SSH to my distribution.

How can I fix this error and start using observer?

**EDIT:** For installing the packages I used the apt-get install command.

With kind regards

PS.: I'm not used to work in Linux but I have a little basic knowledge of it.

Comment: Did you install it through a package manager or did you compile it?

Comment: using the apt-get install command

Comment: Try to compile from sources and follow the instructions from this email http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-January/071650.html maybe it will help you.

Comment: can you run wx:demo(). from the erlang shell.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer may be to set an environment variable. In sh/bash:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

or in csh/tcsh,

```
setenv DISPLAY :0.0
```

Both the above assume you are logged into the head of the computer - not logged in remotely.  Once set graphical apps may start working.

A display manager (e.g. kdm, gdm,...), is typically started at boot to handle a graphical login sequence. This starts X, gets user and password info, logs you in, sets up / runs your desktop and sets up the DISPLAY variable for you.

You haven't indicated enough about your environment to know how much is configured and if you have rebooted since the install if KDE/X. For X to work easily in the long term, you'll want the kdm/gdm configured.

Answer (score 2):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

worked for me when trying to launch the teensy loader on a debian buster install with LXDE